# Service has a dependency on a non-existent service

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I have created a plugin named `SwagMasterAPI`. I need to get retrieve data from different API. But when I try to add it to the service I am getting following error:

`The service "SwagMasterApi\Service\CarService" has a dependency on a non-existent service "MasterDataApi\Model\Api".`

Here are the files I have created.

### carService.php

```
use MasterApi\Model\Api;
class CarService
{
    public function __construct(Api $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }
}
```

### services.xml

```
<service id="SwagMasterApi\Service\CarService">
   <argument type="service" id="MasterApi\Model\Api"/>
</service>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? If that service does not exist, you can not use it

Comment: The convention is to use the FullyQualifiedClassName as the service id, but the names of the class you import and the one you specify in the xml don't match.

Comment: @j_elfering sorry it was typo error while writing the question. Otherwise I am using the same in both service and xml

Comment: can you post where you register the Api service? As it is from a complete different namespace, how do you load it? is it a different composer dependency or do you manage both namespaces in one project?

Comment: @j_elfering I have installed it in the composer.json

Comment: Looks like the package that installed via composer and which contains MasterApi service is not a Shopware plugin and/or does not register MasterApi\Model\Api as a service in DI-container. 

You can register it as a service in your plugin and then pass it to your service (of course it is not best practice) or instantiate it directly in your service constructor (also not best approach).

I dont see any other solution there.

Comment: @Valerii can you show me how ?

Comment: Can you show me the constructor of MasterApi\Model\Api? But in general smth like this:

<service id="MasterApi\Model\Api">
    <!-- some arguments here if needed -->
</service>

<service id="SwagMasterApi\Service\CarService">
   <argument type="service" id="MasterApi\Model\Api"/>
</service>

Comment: @Valerii MasterApi I installed it as a dependency in composer.json {"master-api"}. I am using same code in symfony project where it works. But in shopware I don't know how to implement it

Comment: try enabling autowiring: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html
by adding `<defaults autowire="true" autoconfigure="true"/>` to your service.xml file

Comment: @j_elfering that removed the error.